# Why did I get different results? What's different between two codes?

Tags: javascript, date

it's my first question on this website. haha.
I was trying to make some dummy data which is from yesterday 12AM to now 15 minutes apart.

here is my code.(Javascript)

```
const toDay = new Date();
const fromDay = new Date(
  toDay.getFullYear(),
  toDay.getMonth(),
  toDay.getDate() - 1,
  0,
  0
);
const duration = Math.floor((toDay - fromDay) / (1000 * 60 * 15));
console.log('duration', duration);

let arrayOfData = [];

let dataForX = fromDay;
let dataForY = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
  arrayOfData.push({
    date: dataForX,
    value: dataForY,
  });
  //   dataForX = new Date(dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15));
  dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15);
  dataForY = Math.random() * 100;
}

console.log('arrayOfData', arrayOfData);
```

I wanted some data like Pic1 to make:

[image: Pic1]

But, it resulted in Pic2:
[image: Pic2]

Fortunately, I solve this problem by coding like this,

```
dataForX = new Date(dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15));
```

instead of this.

```
dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15);
```

But, I still don't understand why it came this different result out.

Can you tell me the reason for this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15);` you are actually changing the reference of the same object, thus all dates end up being the same.

When you write `dataForX = new Date(dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15));`, you create a new object(reference) every time. The name of the variable is the same, but the reference changes. You store the old reference first, then create a new one.

Consider the below snippet. The principle is the same as with the dates, but I created an object to make it easier to understand.
When I change foo to be `foo = {bar:10};`, you might think that the value inside the array would be changed to 10, but it isn't. We are creating a new reference, so the old reference is not affected by our change.

```js
const myArray = [];
let foo = {bar: 3};
myArray.push(foo);
console.log(myArray); // will print 3
foo.bar = 5;
console.log(myArray); // will print 5
foo = {bar:10}; // creating a new reference using the same variable name
console.log(myArray); // will still print 5
myArray.push(foo);
console.log(myArray); // will print 5 and 10
foo.bar = 12;
console.log(myArray); // will print 5 and 12
```

Comment: omg, I'm so stupid. I totally got it. Thank you for your help. I love this website!

Comment: Glad I could help. This is actually something that can be quite tricky, even for experienced developers. It's easy to forget that you are changing the same object, or creating a new one, and you can find yourself troubleshooting bugs for hours. No need to feel stupid about it :P

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy of the date object:

```js
arrayOfData.push({
  date: new Date(dataForX.getTime()), // <-- Here
  value: dataForY,
});
```

Example with the change:

```js
const toDay = new Date();
const fromDay = new Date(
  toDay.getFullYear(),
  toDay.getMonth(),
  toDay.getDate() - 1,
  0,
  0
);
const duration = Math.floor((toDay - fromDay) / (1000 * 60 * 15));
console.log(' ~ file: script.js ~ line 10 ~ duration', duration);

let arrayOfData = [];

let dataForX = fromDay;
let dataForY = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
  arrayOfData.push({
    date: new Date(dataForX.getTime()),
    value: dataForY,
  });
  //   dataForX = new Date(dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15));
  dataForX.setMinutes(dataForX.getMinutes() + 15);
  dataForY = Math.random() * 100;
}

console.log('arrayOfData', arrayOfData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```